# trigonometric limit with integral: $\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\int^{\alpha}_{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos x -\cos \alpha}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I've got following limit to calulate:

> $$\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\int^{\alpha}_{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos x -\cos \alpha}}$$

Is there any way to bound it by some "more convenient" limit?

Comment: Since $\alpha$ is small, you can replace the integrand with $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha^2-x^2}}$.

Comment: @vnd You can add an answer with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Tayler expansion, 
$$\cos x\asymp 1-\frac{x^2}2$$ for small $x$.

As @vnd commented, for small $a$ (and $0\le x\le a$ thus $x$ is small), 
$$\cos x\asymp 1-\frac{x^2}2$$
$$\cos a\asymp 1-\frac{a^2}2$$
$$\cos x-\cos a\asymp \frac12(a^2-x^2)$$

Therefore, your integral is asymptotic to
$$\int^a_0 \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx=\sqrt2(\arcsin(\frac{a}{a})-\arcsin(\frac0a))=\color{RED}{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}}$$

---

Another approach is, by enforcing the substitution $x=au$, the integral is transformed to
$$\int^1_0 \frac{a}{\sqrt{\cos au-\cos a}}du$$

Taking the limit into the integral, you can easily get the limit of the integrand $\frac1{\sqrt{\frac{1-u^2}2}}$.

Then, one can easily evaluate the integral to get $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$ by recalling the famous integral $$\int^1_0\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: For this kind of approximation it is necessary to do an exact estimation of the Taylor residuals to ensure that they won't cause any problem.

Comment: The second approach looks more appealing technically as it avoids estimating the Lagrange residuals, but you need to motivate that the limit and the integral can be interchanged. For example, if you prove that the convergence is monotone then you can apply [MCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi's_monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral). To prove monotone convergence, take the derivative of $\frac{a^2}{\cos(au)-\cos a}$ on $a$ and show that is it non-negative for all $u\in(0,1)$

Comment: @A.Γ. Ah! How come I didn’t add my work on MCT!

Answer (score 3):

First, we note that the integral is odd in $a$, so we need only to consider $a>0$.

By performing $u=\cos x$ (and by setting $b=\cos a$), we need to consider the limit
$$
\lim_{b\to 1^-}I(b),\quad\text{where}\quad I(b)=\int_b^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{u-b}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du.
$$
We rewrite the integrand as
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{(u-b)(1-u)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u}}.
$$
The second factor can be estimated as
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+b}}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_b^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{(u-b)(1-u)}}\,du\leq I(b)\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+b}}\int_b^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{(u-b)(1-u)}}\,du.
$$
But (the integral is generalized, but you do the details),
$$
\int_b^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{(u-b)(1-u)}}\,du=\biggl[-2\arctan\frac{\sqrt{1-u}}{\sqrt{u-b}}\biggr]_b^1=\pi.
$$
It follows that
$$
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\leq I(b)\leq \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1+b}}
$$
and so
$$
\lim_{b\to1^-}I(b)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
by the "sandwich theorem".

Comment: It is somehow similar to my solution, though I did not use the substitution. I wrote my solution below for comparison. However, I think the solution via MCT is cool.

Comment: Interesting. Indeed they are similar. I prefer simple solutions if they exist. See you tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a>0$ and rewrite
$$
\cos x-\cos a=2\sin\Big(\frac{a+x}{2}\Big)\sin\Big(\frac{a-x}{2}\Big).
$$
**Estimate:** $t-\frac{t^3}{6}\le\sin t\le t$, $t\ge 0$ gives for $0\le x\le a$
$$
\underbrace{\frac{a^2-x^2}{2}\Big(1-\frac{(a+x)^2}{24}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{(a-x)^2}{24}\Big)}_{\ge\ \frac{a^2-x^2}{2}\big(1-\frac{a^2}{6}\big)\big(1-\frac{a^2}{24}\big)}\le 2\sin\Big(\frac{a+x}{2}\Big)\sin\Big(\frac{a-x}{2}\Big)\le\frac{a^2-x^2}{2},
$$
hence
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x-\cos a}}\le\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{6}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{24}}}. 
$$
**Integrate:**
$$
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\le\int_0^a\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x-\cos a}}\,dx\le\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{6}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{24}}}\to\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}},\quad a\to 0.
$$